# How to write testcase to verify 500 response for flask apis

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I am trying to write unit test cases for flask APIs. I am unable to figure out how to write test cases for 500 internal server errors and custom exceptions in API response.

Here are my books api to get the book by id

```
@BOOKS_BP.route('/<book_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_book(book_id):
    try:
        book = Book.query.filter(Book.id == book_id).scalar()
        if not book:
            raise DBRecordNotFound('No Record Found with ID - {}'.format(book_id))
        book_schema = BookSchema()
        return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'book': book_schema.dump(book)}), HTTPStatus.OK
    except DBRecordNotFound as ex:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(ex)}), HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(ex, exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(ex)}), HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Here is my get book by id test case.

```
import json

from tests.test_base import BaseTestCase
from tests.factories import BookFactory
from http import HTTPStatus


class BooksTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(BooksTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

        book = BookFactory(name='Test Book')
        book.save()
        cls.test_book_id = book.id

    def test_book_by_id(self):
        # For 200 Status
        response = self.client.get('/api/books/{}'.format(self.test_book_id))
        data = json.loads(response.data)
        assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
        assert data['book']['name'] == 'Test Book'

        # For 404 Status
        response = self.client.get('/api/books/123456')
        data = json.loads(response.data)
        assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND
        assert data['message'] == 'No Record Found with ID - 123456'

        # For 500 Status
```

Comment: `response.status_code == 500`  although that just tells you if any error occured on the page (500 is naturally thrown in event of error ...) so you probably need to still check the message if you expect something specific

Comment: @JoranBeasley By sending correct book id it returns 200 response and passing invalid id it returns 404 response. How to raise the exception? to return a 500 response from API.

Comment: `raise Exception("This is an error")` ... or `return ("error occured",500)` ... should work i think? see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/ for better answers